# Injection from union of two uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question: Let X and Y be nonempty sets. Let |X| $\le$ |$\Bbb R$| and |Y| $\le$ |$\Bbb R$|. Prove that |X $\cup$ Y| $\le$ |$\Bbb R$|.

My work:

We know that there exist injections $\quad$f: X -> $\Bbb R$ and g: Y -> $\Bbb R$.

Define a function h(z) = $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
tan^{-1}(f(z)) \quad if z\in X \\ 
tan^{-1}(g(z)) + \pi /2 \quad otherwise \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

So I figured we now need to prove that h is injective, because h includes the domain of X and Y and maps them to the set of real numbers. This is where I got stuck though. 
Conceptually, I think the place I'm stuck is in understanding how h(z) precisely represents the union of X and Y, and maps them to the reals.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As written, $H$ need not be injective. Consider $X=\{\sqrt2/2\}$, $Y=\{-\sqrt2/2\}$ and $f,g$ the natural inclusions

Comment: Hm but is this still true if we allow the cardinality of sets X and Y to be equal to the cardinality of the set of all real numbers? I think this is where I'm running into trouble. I understand this problem when X and Y are less than or equal to the cardinality of the set of Natural numbers (i.e., countable). It's the fact that the set of Reals is not countable - that's the case I don't know how to account for.

Comment: Maybe try defining $h(z) = e^{f(z)}$ if $z \in X$ and $h(z) = -e^{g(z)} $ if $z \in Y$. Then $h : X \cup Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective if $X \cup Y$ is disjoint which is most of the work done

Comment: Ahhhh so is h(z) basically $\pm$ $e^x$, which is an injective function into the reals? So every element of X and Y is captured by h(z), and h(z) is clearly injective if they are disjoint. 
Are we assuming there is no overlap between the ranges of X and Y? 
I'm very new to set theory so I'm not sure which assumptions we're allowed to make

Comment: $h(z)=e^{f(z)}$ if $z\in X$ and $h(z)=-e^{g(z)}$ if $z\in Y\setminus X.$